# Can you make this code choose a random color before betting?

Tags: javascript

```
// CONFIG ////////////////
var initialBetAmount = 2;

var mode = 'martingale'; // can be 'martingale' or 'anti-martingale' (WAT? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_sys.. )

var betColor = 'black'; // can be 'red' or 'black'

//////////////////////////

function tick() {
    var a = getStatus();
    if (a !== lastStatus && "unknown" !== a) {
        switch (a) {
            case "waiting":
                bet();
                break;
            case "rolled":
                rolled()
        }
        lastStatus = a, printInfo()
    }
}

function checkBalance() {
    return getBalance() - 1
}

function getColor(a) {
    return 0 == a ? "green" : a >= 1 && 7 >= a ? "red" : "black"
}

function wonLastRoll() {
    return lastBetColor ? lastRollColor === lastBetColor : null
}
var currentBetAmount = initialBetAmount,
    currentRollNumber = 1,
    lastStatus, lastBetColor, lastRollColor, $balance = $("#balance"),
    $betAmountInput = $("#betAmount"),
    $statusBar = $(".progress #banner"),
    $redButton = $("#panel1-7 .betButton"),
    $blackButton = $("#panel8-14 .betButton"),
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(tick, 500);
```

This is the code. The code works with csgodouble.com and bets on only one color and i want it to choose a random one instead. red/black

Comment: Math.random is your friend. But like any relationship, you have to put effort in.

Comment: @DarkBee Yeah but i am completely new to coding and i have no idea what to do

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't provide much details, my guess is that this is what you need:

```
function getRandomColor(){
  return Math.round(Math.random()) ? 'red' : 'black';
}
```

Comment: Where do i put this? Or do i replace it over var betColor

Comment: `var betColor = getRandomColor();` and just place alexander's code anywhere in the script

Comment: So do get rid of var bet color

Comment: Can you just put it in the code its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

A random color you can generate like that:

```
function randColor() { 
    var col = ""; 
    var possible = "ABCDEF1234567890"; 
    for( var i=0; i < 6; i++ ) 
        col += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)); 
    return "#" + col; 
}
```

Comment: OP only needs black or red, not a random hex based color :)

Comment: @darkbee No, he wants a random color instead of black and red

Comment: Not quite... His script is intended to auto-bet on the link he has provided. Sort of mini-roulette in which there is only red, black and green.

Comment: @darkbee that make sense, but he wrote *i want it to choose a random one instead. red/black*

Comment: Well yes, but in OP's provided code there is a comment stating the bet color only can be black or red ^^

Comment: I thought this is the outgoing state... my bad

Comment: Sorry for the confusion